# How to use python get results from uniprot automatically

Tags: python, biopython

I wanna use a Gene Ontology term to get related sequences in Uniprot. It is simple to do it manually, however, I wanna use python to achieve it. Anybody has ideas with it? For example, I have GO:0070337, then I wanna download all the search results in a fasta file. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to help us help you here.  Your question contains a lot of jargon which is not quite about programming, or is extremely specialized.  It would help if you try to hack some code together, see what works, and ask us specific questions if/when you get stuck.  If you know how to do the task using the shell/terminal by hand, you could write out those commands for us.

Answer (score 4):

To do it fully automated, I recommend to use `requests`:

```
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO  # Python 2
from io import StringIO  # Python 3

params = {"query": "GO:0070337", "format": "fasta"}
response = requests.get("http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/", params)

for record in SeqIO.parse(StringIO(r.text), "fasta"):
    # Do what you need here with your sequences.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the rest interface provided by UniProt. You just have to build a search query with your requirement - i.e. your GO term, species, and file format.

This query will give you all the human proteins with the GO Term for protein binding that haven't been reviewed in fasta format. 
http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=%28go%3A%22protein+binding+%5B0005515%5D%22+AND+organism%3A%22Homo+sapiens+%5B9606%5D%22%29+AND+reviewed%3Ano&sort=score&format=fasta

More details are available at:
http://www.uniprot.org/faq/28